# ¿Cómo usar la función Spread usando solo un valor de la columna objetivo?

Tags: r

Si tenemos el siguiente data frame 'a' con algo como esto:

```r
 > a
    google_prod      Value
1     categoria          ML
2        google         120
3       youtube          24
4     categoria          AO
5        google           2
6       youtube           0
7     categoria          ML
8        google          27
9       youtube           0
10    categoria          AO
11       google           5
12      youtube           0
```

Y quisiéramos llegar a esto:

```
    categoria google_prod    numero
1          ML   google        120
2          ML   youtube        24
3          AO   google          2
4          AO   youtube         0      
5          ML   google         27
6          ML   youtube         0    
7          AO   google          5
8          AO    youtube        0
```

Es decir realizar un tipo de aplicación de la función Spread o alguna parecida, donde se tome solo un valor de la columna google_prod para aplicarlo, en este caso seria el valor 'categoria'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede hacer en una sola llamada, pero con una combinación de `spread()` y `gather()` puede funcionar, aunque es necesario crear primero una variable de agrupación, como hizo @patricio-moracho . Copio el código que usa ambas funciones debajo. También copio el código que usa `pivot_wider()` y `pivot_longer()` porque son las funciones que la nueva versión de `tidyr` sugiere utilizar desde que se implementó su versión 1.0.0.

### `library()` y data.frame

```r
library(tidyverse)

datos <- data.frame(
  google_prod = c("categoria", "google", "youtube", 
                  "categoria", "google", "youtube", 
                  "categoria", "google", "youtube", 
                  "categoria", "google", "youtube"), 
  Value = c("ML", "120", "24", 
           "AO", "2", "0", 
           "ML", "27", "0", 
           "AO", "5", "0"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

### Usando spread() y gather()

```r
datos %>% 
  mutate(grupo = cumsum(google_prod == "categoria")) %>% 
  spread(key = google_prod, value = Value) %>% 
  select(-grupo) %>%
  gather("google_prod", "Value", -categoria)

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# categoria google_prod Value
# <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
# 1 ML        google      120  
# 2 AO        google      2    
# 3 ML        google      27   
# 4 AO        google      5    
# 5 ML        youtube     24   
# 6 AO        youtube     0    
# 7 ML        youtube     0    
# 8 AO        youtube     0
```

### Usando pivot_longer() y pivot_wider()

```r
datos %>% 
  mutate(grupo = cumsum(google_prod == "categoria")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = google_prod, values_from =  Value) %>% 
  select(-grupo) %>%
  pivot_longer(-categoria, names_to = "google_prod", values_to = "Value")

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# categoria google_prod Value
# <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
# 1 ML        google      120  
# 2 ML        youtube     24   
# 3 AO        google      2    
# 4 AO        youtube     0    
# 5 ML        google      27   
# 6 ML        youtube     0    
# 7 AO        google      5    
# 8 AO        youtube     0
```

En ambos casos te recomiendo detenerte en cada proceso del 'pipe' si sientes que no entiendes lo que está pasando.

Answer (score 1):

No se me ocurre como resolverlo con `spread()` me parece que el problema es un poco más complejo. De cualquier forma, si tus datos respetan este formato, dónde cada "grupo" tiene las mismas filas, se podría hacer algo así:

#### 1. A modo de reproducción, un `df` con tu datos:

```
df <- read.table(text="id google_prod      Value
1     categoria          ML
2        google         120
3       youtube          24
4     categoria          AO
5        google           2
6       youtube           0
7     categoria          ML
8        google          27
9       youtube           0
10    categoria          AO
11       google           5
12      youtube           0", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
```

#### 2. Construimos un numerador de cada grupo

```
library("tidyverse")

df %>% 
  mutate(grupo = cumsum(google_prod == "categoria")) -> grupos

grupos
   id google_prod Value grupo
1   1   categoria    ML     1
2   2      google   120     1
3   3     youtube    24     1
4   4   categoria    AO     2
5   5      google     2     2
6   6     youtube     0     2
7   7   categoria    ML     3
8   8      google    27     3
9   9     youtube     0     3
10 10   categoria    AO     4
11 11      google     5     4
12 12     youtube     0     4
```

Como podemos observar, para cada nueva aparición del texto `categoria` definimos un nuevo grupo, esto obviamente depende que cada grupo de datos este secuencialmente ordenado.Y ahora simplemente armamos un nuevo `data.frame` filtrando las filas que no son `categoria` y hacemos un `left_join` con estas, para ubicar esta columna de forma "horizontal":

#### 3. `left_join()`

```
grupos %>% 
  filter(google_prod != "categoria") %>% 
  left_join(grupos %>% 
              filter(google_prod == "categoria"),
            by="grupo") %>% 
  select(categoria = Value.y,
         google_prod = google_prod.x,
         numero = Value.x)

  categoria google_prod numero
1        ML      google    120
2        ML     youtube     24
3        AO      google      2
4        AO     youtube      0
5        ML      google     27
6        ML     youtube      0
7        AO      google      5
8        AO     youtube      0
```